# How to parse/access json from slack action using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, slack-api

I am connecting to the slack API successfully using the subscription events which sends a response which looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"token"=>"[FILTERED]", "team_id"=>"xxx", "api_app_id"=>"yyy", "event"=>{"bot_id"=>"zzz",............
```

I can parse that info using this:

```
json_params = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
user = json_params['event']['bot_id']
```

Now to the problem. I am then adding action buttons, which makes a HTML post response to my URL but the call is in a different format than the subscription event post and JSON.parse is not working.

The format looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"payload"=>"{\"type\":\"block_actions\",\"user\":{\"id\":\"xxx\",\"username\":\"yyy\",\"name\":\"my name\"
```

If I do the same:  json_params = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
It throws this error:

```
JSON::ParserError (783: unexpected token at 'payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22block_............
```

Also tried

```
json_params = JSON.parse(request)
```

That returns //TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Request into String):

And I tried

puts request and puts request.raw and JSON.parse(request.body) and puts request.body too and they didn't work, I am new to rails so struggling on this for ages, any ideas?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why on earth you're using a form to send requests to the endpoint that processes your slack events callbacks, what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

```
Parameters: {"payload"=>"{\"type\":\"block_actions\",...
```

This is the request body and query parameters parsed into a Ruby Hash held in `params`. The key "payload" contains the JSON. JSON parse only `params["payload"]`.

See [Action Controller Overview - Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).